# Android Studio [JDBC]: Why I'm not able to reach the database

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc, android-studio

I know there are some topics discussed this matter before but I tried almost all of the solutions with no luck, and I know some don't recommend using JDBC for dealing with DB in android but as for the purpose of my university project I need to use it.

I have a DB hosted by Hostgator and I'm sure of the information I'm using (Host name, user & pass) as I tried them with other Java IDE and they worked perfectly, so no my pc in not blocked either. I added the Mysql J connector to Android Studio as library, tried 2 versions the latest one and 3.0.17, but there's no luck, I don't know what I'm doing wrong as there's no errors or exceptions appearers in the logcat.

this is the code contain the connection to DB: (P.S.I removed exceptions statements to shorten the code)

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
Connection start;
```

// tried localhost it didn't work

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/abed_impresent";
String username = "abed_bayoun";
String pass = "xxxxx";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        start = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);

    Statement my;
    if (start != null) {
        test = new ArrayList<>();
            my = start.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = my.executeQuery("select code from Tutors");
            while (res.next()) {
                test.add(res.getString("code"));
            }
            for (int c = 0; test.size() > c; c++) {
                if (text.getText().equals(test.get(c))) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(tStart.this, tChoose.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(tStart.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                } else continue;
            }
    }
    return null;
```

all codes under if statement is begin skipped, as it seems the app can't connect to DB.

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the relevant details of the exception.

Comment: there's no errors or exceptions, program works but without connecting to DB

Comment: *But without connecting to the DB* if the application cannot connect to the database then an exception is thrown. Looks like you're not logging the exception, thus you cannot check how to fix the issue. Please log the exception, copy the stacktrace and edit your post, otherwise we're unable to help you.

Comment: im using e.printstacktrace(); but I can't find any exceptions in logcat

Comment: In which part are you using that? Because if no exception is thrown then it means you can connect and work with the database with no problems.

Comment: in catch body. if the app connected to the DB then why the code is not executed? kindly, can check the code and tell me if there's a coding mistake preventing the code from being executed.

Comment: I would remove the `if-else` from the `for` loop and just log a message or something to check that the `test` variable was filled as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I know what I was doing wrong,

I putted this code in a separate try-catch statement

```
start = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);
```

which is somehow blocked the other codes from getting the value of start and deal with it as a null value.

I included the rest of the code in the same try-catch statement and that did the trick for me.

Thanks everybody for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly not recommended to use jdbc driver on android (as far I can remember ony one jdbc  version works with android). Instead of jdbc driver consider creating web service which provides content from your database.